# Writing a function with a variable

Tags: variable

trying to write this function, while b,d are known numbers and hj is the variable

[image]

thank you very much

Comment: Use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html), i.e., `Dj[hj_] := Piecewise[{{hj + b, hj <= 2 d - b}, {(hj + b)/2 + d, hj > 2 d - b}}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `functionName[variable_]:=If[variable>something,` what to do if true`,` what to do else`]`.